# Can my undergraduate research thesis be published in a scientific paper? If so, how should I go?

Tags: publications, thesis, research-undergraduate

I'm starting my bachelor's degree thesis and i will do some research work. If I achieve good results can my work be published? If so , who should get the credits? I'm afraid that my prof or his research lab can publish/include my work in some their future papers without my name.

Comment: Your thesis will possibly be too big to publish it "as is" in a paper or as an article. You could of course write a publication based on your thesis, but should avoid self-citing it. (e.g. in Germany a bachelor's thesis is not published and in result not publicly available to everybody)

Comment: So if my professor publish a new paper and my work gets a "section" of the paper, should I be mentioned?

Comment: @Voxis Yes, if your professor writes a paper based on your work, you should be co-author.  If you write the paper, your professor should be co-author.

Comment: In which country is this?

Comment: When you are the main contributor of a work you can claim authorship. Having submitted your thesis to an examination office puts you in a good position to provide proof on this. The easy way is to talk to your supervisor and mention your wish (and right) to be named as (main/co/whatever) author

Comment: @AndréKleinschmidt I agree, but then one should also take the lead on writing the text, making publication-quality visualisations, etc..

Comment: Most academics I've met would be pleased if an undergrad project resulted in a publication, and would be quite supportive.  It would be extra work for you of course, but it would reflect very well on you if you're planning a career in academia or even some industries.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. Being new user I cannot upvote your comments :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your work is good enough, it deserves to be published. It doesn't matter if it is the result of a hobby, undergraduate studies, or your main job as a researcher.

Summarizing it to make it fit into the space allotted in a journal or conference proceedings will be a daunting task, ask your advisor for guidance and help.

Comment: What if I do not have an advisor? Is there any online facility to gain help?

Answer (score 3):

As vonbrand has said, it is the quality of work, rather than the degrees behind the person who wrote it, that should determine whether or not something can be published. There are *very* few journals who have standing bans on publishing undergraduate research, though be aware that preparing a paper for publication is a fairly daunting task.

My advice would be to talk to your advisor about whether or not your work is in the position to be published as a stand-alone paper, or if it's going to be incorporated into a larger paper.

In the first case, the next step is to talk to them about what still needs to be done, what journal to target, and the steps you need to take to get going on that path. In the second case, it's largely a matter of asking if you'll be included as an author on that paper, or end up in the acknowledgements section. Having a clear and direct conversation up from will help things in the long run.

For reference, my undergraduate thesis was published with me as the first author on it.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above answers, there are in fact, some journals which are dedicated exclusively to the publication of undergraduate research. It might be easier for your paper to get accepted in such journals. The [Council of Undergraduate Research](https://web.archive.org/web/20171125142254/https://www.cur.org/resources/students/undergraduate_journals/) provides a list of popular undergraduate journals.

However, you can also submit your paper to any regular journal as very few journals have restrictions on publishing papers by undergraduates. Here is [an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20171113065743/http://blogs.plos.org/thestudentblog/2014/03/25/final-steps-undergraduate-research-experience-peer-review-publishing/) on publishing as an undergraduate that you might find interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, my first PhD student published a paper on his undergraduate work (I was also a co-author of the paper), so it is certainly possible (and indeed a good way of learning about research practices if you are interested in that as a career).  As the other answers suggest, quality is the key.

Comment: Is it possible to show a undergraduate paper in my PhD which I published before joining PhD ?